# Exception: Failed to attach BPF to kprobe when executing sudo opensnoop-bpfcc

Tags: ebpf, kprobe, bcc-bpf

When I try to execute `sudo opensnoop-bpfcc` I get this message:

```
In file included from /virtual/main.c:4:
In file included from include/linux/sched.h:14:
In file included from include/linux/pid.h:5:
In file included from include/linux/rculist.h:11:
In file included from include/linux/rcupdate.h:40:
In file included from include/linux/preempt.h:81:
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7:
In file included from include/linux/thread_info.h:38:
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53:
./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:150:2: warning: "Compiler lacks ASM_GOTO support. Add -D __BPF_TRACING__ to your compiler arguments"
      [-W#warnings]
#warning "Compiler lacks ASM_GOTO support. Add -D __BPF_TRACING__ to your compiler arguments"
 ^
1 warning generated.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/opensnoop-bpfcc", line 127, in <module>
    b.attach_kprobe(event="sys_open", fn_name="trace_entry")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bcc/__init__.py", line 526, in attach_kprobe
    raise Exception("Failed to attach BPF to kprobe")
Exception: Failed to attach BPF to kprobe
```

I don't understand how to fix it. I've just installed bcc tools using this command

```
sudo apt-get install bpfcc-tools linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

as suggested on the github page https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/INSTALL.md#ubuntu---binary

The running OS is 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

Comment: I believe [this bcc issue](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/2119) is related (and proposes a workaround).

Comment: They 're taking about 5.0 kernel version do you think it's the same for 4.18?

Comment: Yes. Yonghong gives additional details [in this commit log for kernel samples](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6bf3bbe1f4d4cf405e3c2bf07bbdff56d3223ec8), the issue has been around since 4.17.

Comment: Thanks again, so I have to build it from the source code because the package maybe is not updated.

Comment: You can try to build locally, I don't remember facing this issue last time I build on Ubuntu 18.04, so maybe it's been fixed somehow. Otherwise, try adding the `#define asm_volatile_goto(x...)` line [at the beginning of the BPF code](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/6c793317dac5866db2899e62504d047a02c089b7/tools/opensnoop.py#L81)... I'm afraid I don't have anything easier to suggest at the moment :/.

Comment: After built it locally.
modprobe: FATAL: Module kheaders not found in directory /lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic
Unable to find kernel headers. Try rebuilding kernel with CONFIG_IKHEADERS=m (module)
chdir(/lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic/build): No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tcpconnect", line 223, in <module>
    b = BPF(text=bpf_text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bcc/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    raise Exception("Failed to compile BPF module %s" % (src_file or "<text>"))
Exception: Failed to compile BPF module <text>

Comment: Do you have kernel modules installed on your system? This sounds like you don't. (`sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`)

Comment: I started again from installing the OS . Thanks again. You are great.
1) sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
2)sudo apt-get -y install bison build-essential cmake flex git libedit-dev \
  libllvm6.0 llvm-6.0-dev libclang-6.0-dev python zlib1g-dev libelf-dev
3) git clone https://github.com/iovisor/bcc.git
mkdir bcc/build; cd bcc/build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
make
sudo make install

This sequence worked :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it working! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to compile bcc from source code instead of installing it using the package.

1. Install linux kernel headers

`sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

2. Install required dependencies

`sudo apt-get -y install bison build-essential cmake flex git libedit-dev \ libllvm6.0 llvm-6.0-dev libclang-6.0-dev python zlib1g-dev libelf-dev`

3. Compile bcc from source code

```
git clone https://github.com/iovisor/bcc.git
mkdir bcc/build; cd bcc/build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: on Ubuntu 18.04 and some other Debian based distros you also need to install `libfl-dev`

Answer (score 1):

@Maicake is right. Compiling and installing from source did work for me. Here are the steps to install on Ubuntu 22.04:

1. Follow the steps described [here](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/INSTALL.md#ubuntu---source). Specifically for Ubuntu 22.04 you may need to [make some changes](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/2340#issuecomment-1250073498) after cloning the bcc repository.
2. Add the following line to your `.bashrc` file:

   `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/bcc/tools`
3. Create a symlink to python3 as most of the tools use `python` (not `python3`) to run the scripts.

   `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`